# Library work in java file but not found in xml file

Tags: xml, android-studio, github, android-library

I am on android studio dolphin 2021.3.1 patch 1 and I'm trying to use `mukeshsolanki.otpview` from GitHub, in the java file the library is imported and works perfectly but when I try to use it in the XML file I don't find it.

https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview

please can someone help me?

Comment: hey this was made using jetpack compose so this is why you don't need any xml file for this for more information visit the below link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

Comment: @Hrusikesh but i have seen videos on youtube and they use it in xml normally how can i do that ?

Comment: Does this work for you or still you have any issue with this library ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the JitPack repository to your build file. Add it to your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
         implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.2'

}
```

Add OTPView in the xml like below `otp_auth.xml`

```
<com.mukesh.OtpView
  android:id="@+id/otp_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  app:itemCount="6"
  app:lineColor="@color/colorPrimary"
  app:viewType="line"
  />
```

and then in your activity `OTPActivity.kt`

```
 private OtpView otpView;
 otpView = findViewById(R.id.otp_view);
 otpView.setListener(new OnOtpCompletionListener() {
   @Override public void onOtpCompleted(String otp) {
     // do Stuff
     Log.d("onOtpCompleted=>", otp);
   }
 });
```

Comment: For the activity file its okey but what you did in the xml file i cant do it when write "com.mukesh.OtpView" i get an error.

Comment: Can you try it again by adding the dependency first go through the above steps again.

Comment: Every time i got the same error "Missing classes" The following classes could not be found:
- com.mukesh.OtpView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Comment: I'am using java and its written in kotlin maybe that is the problem ?

Comment: Hey I have added the particular version can you try with that and let me know whether it works or not  ?

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting me but I didn't want to stagnate any longer now i use this library https://github.com/aabhasr1/OtpView it's the same things and it work for me.